# wordpress himalays theme show more content in about us widget

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm useing the himalayas theme on my wordpress side. On frontpage there are widgets.

The about us widget shows a content preview of a page.

How can I show more content in this widget? You can see in the picture the right side there is a reade more button, I want more text instead of the read more button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer from themegrill (Developer of Himalayas theme).

'About us' widget fetches the excerpt of the page. To display the content as your wish, You can put your contents in the excerpt box. You can enable excerpt box from the screen option in the right top corner of your dashboard.